# Unexpected cURL response

Tags: php, curl

I receive an unexpected response from API. Everything worked perfectly until I changed the web hosting (I'm not 100% for sure)

```
noofitem: 348 - {"isError":false,"messages":["WARNING: You have not made \u200b\u200bchanges to the product documentation elements, they were not saved."],"results":[]}
noofitem: 349 - {"isError":false,"messages":["WARNING: You have not made \u200b\u200bchanges to the product documentation elements, they were not saved."],"results":[]}
noofitem: 350 - {"isError":false,"messages":["WARNING: You have not made \u200b\u200bchanges to the product documentation elements, they were not saved."],"results":[]}
```

after 2-3 minutes the script (cURL) stops and prints following symbols

```
��}�r�H��1�P�xDb��.�L ��2ݭn]<����:ZE�(��A���.�x^�o��}ا}����#�%�YU���@����h@Uefefef���ޟ^���.c{�/�{k�ڕ5 G�����+���Vˤ�]�X���g(v�)Ħ��P����M}�P,���x[��"�a����kգ��Ċ�"��lڈQ�,��?���C�t�����z���13�[��M\/�\'`伳�`d����ш�X�E�ߧ63�zC#czo��q�S�3���|r\N``6��H��HCB���2��е��H��=�32���PFA0i��wwwz�s�]�s�i�1���Z�����S;t�X�6U�����!C*��ϝ0/x0�A�E'��Lhnom5���6�ww��n�M�LJ��V�٩bOQ�) ���=�:�_�G�ƳԚ[�M}��1�e�i�"��7��<6��zKEb��?C�=ȟچބ�Ɩ���6��������iI}��j���=�PY�QE�z���G'���'o�J�E��l�k1f�E�S�cl�%������@Yj�����?,�T ;�P��s@�>tݡ����Ac�{0�c�~0:N�:�g漾����j44���6�a��x���G�J.��0�ڦ;��  ��#":�5��۳�jpr������?", ��6�4��Ħ���X�?8}0u�a%� ��eu�Uu:}��U�;�����{G�*�������k��g�4�U���]�|��ZZNH=�~��R̬5��V���I�m�����WEj��� ��l N�"���&Xb۲��:�W4A�t   �A��~��{�awg�o�)�2L��m��g O�$<�4_s���iT�߭��O��������z_X?�\^ۺ� �����!�ï�? ���xu���U�7��?|u��D�h��&���U�65�)�ֵf����ǐ0d���{���S�� ��qݦ:W�  O�9��X�����5�n9�(�b��T��Y���i���Ti���V^L�\�F��ʗ�}�!�V��qH�A}E#��l5w�vv6kM�@���yEN�E�<��&#�d�7-������1�Vs�@�AH��@���z,=����H ,-���\��/��W�/���h�lZ�6,d32k���~��ď�f�GG�]�^Lc�Ϸ���Q�����i\]����2Sہ!��j��x��!�\�3.v�P�Și$߿�Αpd[ �p@���3p�_u�*sn>]�=v�hQ�B8P�j�p\��������6�lonl�<<���WȢ@��~�*j;��W>�Y�!1k8°W!"��'n� Ŵ|�t-�u ��ETИhT��;�L#O�:�5"2�#�FS�����(a)/u�Z��� ə/���3_�1�3߸R,�i MA&���s� �r��/6���\�2 ���D���]�>I�<��$0:�Gte���`�W��b��?�\g�v�m�d&�t���"F�h���B&�6s���m�~-(�����W֜�_A�k��+UHV����2�&�r�*RM��ÑYU�b5p�jdX�^fĥ�MX�����>_� �3>�v�� ^PūR��H��.�@��eߵ■������V|ݷz����X�ADB��9eV�J�u   ��0��<�8=���{y�[�������P��eQ��h}z�� *���C3áݴw��~ww4l3Ռw'�_�!��k>D��\����� S��M떠p�����S*LHBz�dV  ����/�a��'1������8�b���D*f��� �@� �2e>�xW�q�� ���Ao��z�n7��u�~G`4�#+*ⱱ{��� ����*�Q�?�r@k�{�����Y�`�MvɡT�a�+�P�����N���Ә���R�ՊmA��Z  m���A��L�����x�qd�� k68�4� qe/āҕ��G����w�ԧ�ثC�l9��[���`�2�S$S   !Q�֭k�Ն�V�吖O���܀����a�B&�m�G4�s~Fu)�U���}�H��Hu3���2t?�j����#:Mv��%�!p�ra� שi�Էjⷶ�/�,:1Ka��"����3��&�#��R%�� :p�V b�M,����äXI�8����-�L�Y�j�WS�.%���NND�%%�r@d�jw ��w�ز���a��K���c����I��u$�Ēh�p�-U�,���ָ�<����˸T�^=�    �����,�I��Ǜw����e1�2�Y��-������ڲ���Y�*odK�)ga3�I�ײh��֌�҆�,��V5� MjiO��pnL�/aI3��-�� � �,�2�3�N)�Yڪ,g7�}1�2�����Y�&:���B5^����   �� =���ӂ���̰�0�|"[��g�C�d�^��'�Ɂ�fX��h�z(�`"���Jߵ�"��o����ჰ&tQ&`�l����H�g(�- m/������h��x�O��u �ʹq߲GnȂ��u:s���)��~V�y��L4X�<���>YTz��   �K&8��<�Q��x�G!�h���F��D�8��e�@����!�|y��/�� K.�Q���+C^tim������������c'оЪ?qT|i���k;��o�X�a��]���I���h9P:��j��%r��7���j�k��'.����L����x~���E�t>]vO/����f���5��lC�l��]���q���~::�;���.;O �Cd�i��b�G��wR0�q�|<�������iw��\��n*C��ò`���i��G�v�E����/�����s����'��з� ��'� �l��!�j��j_>�����&�,��ڎ�ߩ�|R�]ԇس&f3��id}w��P#�� 1w�Xq���t;Fͅ��V$^-�xM���Og|E&O��-g(�_�j(b�"�X�ʗ�ic ��1�P��o��9�@F���D�'�~VZh�Ъ�9�������e?�X��&�#��-��+T/ב�v~���N�qk��0�� B�����A���L��U)�k<�Bn)��P2�i��\���0��r�Xɜ��ϵ  /$s����v)��S2�������|�D�ى䳝H%������F�&ƀ�xb�ēeI��X�� &�%5ј*��S��f�7�X�O4�Pn� W����jR�[�㢓��C��O���N/S�d�c��N��3�S��:����ꐳڸ[a�����o^ؘ�*�cC��z��ot�RX�#T,4S�꯱"�>4�1b�՗>+=֞|����aZ���^��@"�j|����>��Fl�Vf�u�N&�~j�ZE"OY��w��!���ŧcr���E� u����^pCo4����^Ӗ��g���G��Y�q��7 +I�����ģ_`c�%���;�8r��V K��'�x+��E�s±������%���bq`vxv�=�<:"�ݟ���_����}����,i��^� �bi�{��Bұa/͎�\���F���rK&8?˴% z���"GABi�^l�� ����C�bo���Rb��k48�sLX�Q��� N�$�L]���Y�!Ȋ���ǯ����|������%!W�%���֊p .E��喑�%��ҳ8�ʾf���L-@=�t�hX�c��A�����O�����24E�?�tqyv����C��J�㳟~�r+f�N/;���=x�HbG��O��~s�凇(��#�{<��__WB o����E�c�m��]f5����M��E���������T�c��ZDQ����d�� Z��m�1�s�����W������\�N��c 4�9��Ī������[�4�Y�Ʈ�k��'F�=�����_����W+x�OX|��#�E�����l�l�y*2����:�H6A���1�CE���}Ӛ ��q�шYj3�����G�{'�<�&��3dQ���4`�n���$�nl��ČX��@��2P_E�o:�5[��Կ3Ec� ]�ܺ�ӂ.�C�Ȅ>tR55Wm���}\�O�����&�����W�No��D6)�"��LRb�@.����!_�ϗnu�j��p�F8���������A���$\�f)ɡ\C�$D��ZV�^o7b�)�w�x�]{y��,uU]__�؈��&wF���<�2�i)�ia{�/�ֳ��k R�g8��3z��T�r&���)i�Hv,'��+U�T�X0��#��-���,0����z�HF@F:���D��/`T.=ͫWUy�V&��R̚�F�kUHC,ʹD8iz ���2�㏃����"v�:���aU����|-{��Z ���o�I���#͋1��Ȉs�m��M�j�acЗ9u��U*�1x��l@C��t�dF��;���� �����ǐ6d�g��8�H���c��W��� ���*�@'��Q ������d)������"W�.�w�;Z3��4��s��k�Ս���?���?d5vq�c�x��U���r$t3�?#����  F:����m��~� Diq ��v('����   m���Q���=>f��TJ�?3�"����Ӧ��7c�xt���l��T�&��Q�7i&��+���߃��)�����~�kj�a��F���n�너<��J����8=�[f<�%=@�@�DE�ЗK�B�M�Ү�qʨ���x���q.Q�%W���'!��^:���0SZ610��|��l�`���Oذ���"�������Ϣ���=���{   ���fŕ�b�S�{4�����Oksz�m�D� ��x�\�&tK�~��=>�T���ϓ��S&� !Кl�����Ѕɭ��K5��=��B�G���*�<������g�C���� f[,�<�'� ԛ&�v�������GT��j@,g���G�بp��D/��e�E�^"O2"��;6�1E�����'|�4m�S �xW� ҽ�ĩ<�؉�o���Jc���PO.�*�6��ɾE��xܼ}̒�O����ۦ��Q��\n&��lH�Cm鶔�!ǁ�̬E$FVi# b_��bg��Vu ��f;���K������C�HL>�c�}=�L���J���P��\7sM<�-�q^�!���GEl����D��9ɫ������������{}����F�����gF���4o�4ߴ3���=� �S�e�#S:�I�B&R�+�� !��w�H���>7�'� Wc������<��K\7��Ԭ'�����S��C��.���_�o�o���k��z&^�o�v��#"2&P�B���~Զ�o��)���1��b�]c��'�a�vʟ�� �������u!D�/�-7���9�վ��4�~�!oH�IW�B���N�Xwz��=�,�A]m� ,8�d&��b��Kcb�!�D�e5��ؕRD�5!|2��R{5�Vȸ�7�#1b)S(��'0��("��6���*��l0F^�hB�� ߫aCR������1�S,�����h��L�%�̖O�)�F���7�r'C�8��wқS9H�.z���;�#���~!�̴��%(��`�s�qT��,� xV��8�Q�$6f�FI��h{���~h;�V�Tަ�T����O9e&/���.�#����g�Q!9����@�V`Y��e�[" 1 ���t����4Ȣ�n� &X���9�`�g���ZpR��d�z�%=C����i֋hԳN�,ܶn=��������{Ο%���� �ژ�|��O�B�� �\��"� �5B��m�K+�ii��%�Nn�K���!-��,�L��݊�L���� ��ؤ���(Ӵ2"9���o�_,�?�j4�}�0������fkk�m����3����4�Y��:p[���%>k���%�7=�:_��l��Lǻ�=U��a���������[�����=�"�qr��9C�=S8[O/���1[V4��֋��|�/�i��w��,Z�BM����7f3K#��N6�4�~���G��i�Hy�C���,Y���I@��E����6h�Z��lsk���VsF)�E.�tҽ �CУ_�������FSol����� ���q�`�??��v}�W�:�ʩ��u���9;2��%���PY�}�WNX��xU%��=�3Y�^�k)�_X=�j�����V�L2�y���Î���D��5�f}�~F�FS��MO��2'XF!����`j���UiG�|��R���#�YQ�$Z�Χp�W���g�e11��=j�<�e�x06�nnlom��e�Z� 7���8۴��ܤzV���Ā�$��Qq�S��Y'ij��>Β��H0t�������<+DT�P�nO���;�X��{��������{V:���~�� �݋��o��zP����Rk�;ך�������^���g��n��y�+�ylk� VT��ub��=�<�՘jh�5��׌�`�Lv�iU~�*���p��ޡ՜�_�W/����4�yD���3�Gm#��S�g�b;0O��Oє���F2�!z�� {�~�3+��s8!Vq��ĳ�1߸���>�gk��9X����#���F:�h��M��3��#���S��9���5����o6ĩ�x\,d�:b<����L�[Sb>u|J�l�9��� ^ (��L����mq�"f+�   �I�c�.xi�?p�:&����_�8�\�,�7���/�n��W�Kg��7N4�!D��D��i���s�Eh��Ј�Ɔv�:~��������� ��� �gPz�ٝ`�Ld�h���1���wUG[UN�~�h�4����A���o��tٚ­ X�a��#��e��*��$� �ѧbK�xBU�Mp�մ]@K�KF���iΈ��L�^�U�� TG����&F0-��u�G�Z�iY�h��X��g�it��I�H��b2=k�-�p_���� Z��Rq-���O�tcX`evS�d��y\oaymx�Ur�w�����?/�-!�F'��;�N�@B�N�8d�X��\Ż�I!�{�3�ĒUG���U�d�l�a���w��M^�2q]�tL�MG6PX&�e�*��T��3�$��'rm:|~�㇪�$�f�(�.. ?������)�X�RQy"����ȬO��O9���%'mT��0�A� �_.��x�'��d7��I�P)^��&�&d�)��<[�bi���O�'�P�s�;;�; �kL��[FG�|.x�t[.jw�l �cr�^����R�m' dcJrG���qf��!�8ԭI��E�G�|�]V�*9 ��i�j�r�A�K幖�I�Of�>n�x�-'�Y�7�E�8��Z�   ?C��[   �G�.�HSģ��E��ȱ�Wߐӏ���25_�����xʾ���~#V��!�}e|�}cu�� D��e�9,��x�0vN���+�pW2�x|%,���#|EceA���/a�   ��Am�[�W�\>x�������.��t�$���۷��|�?}��}����@����W�)�Z]��nmV8�Jc���_�� ��i}��b�/�$�V�B��FL�(@yG�l�,�w�O�p������7�6��}�<:;���� '��ß���)�p��������b>    �G'��Ry�铪m}����At�k"�X�����!,��D����t��'�N-eO>��n�s K_�,8^jS�D�n�i��m_�7ɨ�!'�E~U��2 �.�.���L�(a˙�d�cft:=1 t=*�L���"��^6���b�+��:��}�����m����
```

http://prntscr.com/esbtcr

There are like 700 items but after that cURL is not working.

Have you seen that before?

```
    public function execute() {
    $hash = sha1(http_build_query($this->data) . sha1($this->password));
    $request_data = array(
        'code' => $this->code,
        'username' => $this->username,
        'data' => $this->data,
        'hash' => $hash
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = $this->api_url.'/'.$this->resource.'/'.$this->action;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($request_data));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $this->date_sent = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: How do you call the curl?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I've updated my post

Comment: Try inserting encoding -> `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');`

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos it seems is not working.. same output

Comment: If it's json try this -> `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));` (try it also with the combination of the above)

Comment: I'm still confused. I also tried to run the script on localhost and it worked perfectly. ..so something is happening on the shared

Comment: Does tables and database have the same encoding as your localhost database/tables? i.e `utf8_unicode_ci`